# Network faulty at startup Ubuntu 18.04.3 updated 'till today

Tags: boot, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have a small problem. 
When I cold boot my Ubuntu system all is fine, but when I open Chrome 
pages DO NOT LOAD and I get all the time 'error couldn't find internet/ Check provider'. ufw is set active
So I triggered on my modem and reset it ... no resolve. 
But when I disconnect my WiFi in Ubuntu (airplane mode) and reconnect it 
all is fine and everything works good. So this is purely at startup. 
Running on an iwlwifi driver. Broadcom chipset.

Ubuntu is untweaked, no special arrangements running on a Dell E6500 P9700 CPU/ 4Gb RAM

When I do this workaround I can work with Ubuntu like a charm ....

It happened since updates came by 2 weeks ago, but I can't find update history for checking what causes the problem .

Or should I just wait for a Chrome / Ubuntu update ?

Edit: I tested my Chromium browser (my privacy browser) and it has the same issues as Chrome .... so that brings me to the networkmanager or the iwldriver going faulty at startup . I ditched Firefox so I can't test it .

Comment: Has the driver/driver version for the network card changed after the update?

Comment: No but there was an APACHE network update if I remeber well

Comment: If Apache is not running on your machine, then that likely wouldn’t have done it.

Comment: Updates today resolved the problem: I saw one as a wpa(....) update and there was also a Chrome update .... SOLVED everything

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why: a Bug in LivePatch !!!

I turned it off and logout of it / reboot and all is fine .

So I will wait for updates or so ..

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Updates solved the problem described as UBuntu basis updates (I saw while updating a remark of wpa .... passing by and it solved the problems I had.